# If we hit an electron will it go to an excited state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, atoms, metals

For example i have a block of silicon doped with phosphorous and i hit it hard with a hammer will the energy get transfered to the block and make the electrons excited?

Comment: Do you know what excited electrons means?

Comment: @annav It's possible. The mechanical energy is converted to heat energy, which promotes an electron (like 4s to 3d). I just don't know if it would happen.

Comment: @annav yes when an electron from a ground stage goes to  a higher level the electrons become excited. Also can you answer this question if you know the answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175811/how-does-a-photon-drive-out-the-electrons-in-a-solar-cell

Comment: The electron does not become excited, it goes to a higher energy state, called an excited state. One has to be careful of terminology in physics. The electron is an elementary particle and can gain or lose energy when free  through electromagnetic interactions, or go to a higher or lower excited state when bound. Excitation  is an attribute of a bound system as a whole, not of an electron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to the band structure. In a solid the energy levels are not the same as an isolated atom, there are bands instead of levels. So if you are thinking about an electron jumping between discrete energy levels then that is probably not going to happen. Particularly if you are thinking that an electron will de-excite emitting a photon, then that is improbable.

When you talk about exciting an electron in a solid, you have to be more specific about which levels you are talking about. Some bands are populated at the room temperature and some get excited as you increase the temperature. Some kinds require little energy to excite, while others need a lot. (Think of a semiconductor changing its resistance with temperature due to excitation of higher levels and when you hammer the block its temperature may rise).